# Plugin: Google Analytics for Dashboard error - Timestamp is too far from current time

Tags: plugins, errors, login, dashboard, google-analytics

Has anyone used the **[Google Analytics for Dashboard](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard/)** plugin?

I've installed it successfully, but whenever I try to link it to my Google Account using the Start Login Process button, I keep getting a weird message that goes like:

```
Timestamp is too far from current time: <a Unix timestamp here>
```

I'm using WordPress 3.1.3.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Thanks,
m^e

Comment: Check your server time.

Comment: @Hameedullah Khan as an answer please

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your server time is not correctly set. Please correct your server time, you may want to restart your web server after fixing the time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm on a VPS and I can progress as far as syncing the time with ntpdate... however, when it comes to resetting the hardware clock to the same - I'm being stopped by the VPS. Don't know how to progress beyond this point. Any ideas?

Comment: syncing with ntpdate is fine.

Comment: Hmm.. wasn't quite right about the hwclock earlier on. It's ntpdate which is being refused permission to update the system time. I keep getting the following error:  
ntpdate[31778]: step-systime: Operation not permitted  

Any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks. Issue resolved. It arose out of the exact same reason as you mentioned.